# Chatter Feed Disabled, Still Email Action not visible

Tags: apex, lightning, salesforce-support

I have disabled the chatter feed. Also I have dynamic action on compact layout on for Case. I am not able to see the Email quick action.

Comment: Check if 'Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items' is enabled under, Setup-->Customize-->Cases-->Support Settings.